# React native Model popup with Check box list style Issue

Tags: react-native

I make check box list on Model Pop up by using react native multiple select checkbox list listed but it take full screen height i am not able to fix this issue please Any body help me
below is my  Model Pop up Code

```
  [![<Modal
         animationType="slide"
         transparent={true}
         visible={this.state.modalVisible}
         onRequestClose={() => {
         Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
         }}
          >
            <View style={styles.ModalcenteredView}>
         
            <View style={styles.ModalView}>

            <View style={{height:'30%'}}>

            <SelectMultiple
          items={this.state.ParticipantCheckBox}
          // renderLabel={renderLabel}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedFamilyMembers}
          onSelectionsChange={this.SelectFamilyMembers} />
          </View>

          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', flex:1,height:'1%'}}>

          <TouchableHighlight style={{height:'5%'},\[styles.ModalCloseButton\] }
                onPress={() => {
                  this.HideShowFamilyMemberModel(false);
                }}
              >
                <Text style={styles.ModalCloseButtonTextStyle}>Close</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{height:'5%'},\[styles.ModalSaveButton\] }
                onPress={() => {
                  this.SaveFamilyMemberModel(false);
                }}
              >
                <Text style={styles.ModalSaveButtonTextStyle}>Save</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

              
            
            </View>

          </View>
        </Modal>][1]][1]
```

Comment: what do you expect to have?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your modal like this

```
<Modal>
//this is parent view
<View>
    //set this vide at the center of parent view and set height 40% or 30%
    <View>
        <ScrollView>
            …
             ...
</ScrollView>
</View>
</View>
</Modal>
```